# how to remove "=20" at end-of-line html/text emails

Tags: email, newline, htmltext, hmail-server

I am using vbs and hMailServer to send html/text emails.

I noticed that for the text section of the email `=20` was added to the end of almost every line making it harder to read the text section of the email.

How can I prevent getting these `=20` at the end of most of the lines?

This image shows what I am finding -- note, not all new line breaks have the `=20` marker at the end:

[image: see sample text]

None of these are working: `vbCrLf`, `vbNewLine`, `vbCr`, `vbLf`, `Chr(13)`, `Chr(10)`.

Except, for some reason, adding a period "." just before the linebreak (like this `"." & vbCrLf`) makes the `=20` go away. And it looks like the same is true for lines ending with a dash `-` and/or the line *starting with* a space; and lines with no text.

For what it is worth, this is how I am sending it to hMailServer.

```
    Set hms= Server.CreateObject("hMailServer.Message")
    hms.Body = emailtext_no_HTML
    hms.HTMLBody = emailtext_with_HTML
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a workaround, by adding a space to the start of each new line.